# Select where one component of a DATETIME field is a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to run a `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` condition that looks at just one component of a `DATETIME` field?  For example, I want to select all entries where the hour component = 20.  So if I had three entries:

```
2014-03-15 20:05:32.000
2013-06-02 20:57:15.000
2014-03-15 00:57:32.000
```

I would want the query to select the first two entries, but not the third.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE DATEPART('hh', created) = 20;
```

Comment: Yep that's it.  I wasn't using the right keywords when I Googled before posting, and I found something suggesting `datepart` just after I posted the question.  Thanks!